Is it possible to manage microk8s local cluster using the Official Kubernates VS code Extension?
I am failing to use Kubernates Extension with microk8s local cluster but it keeps on complaining about missing kubernetes dependencies.
I am trying to use the Official Kubernates VS code Extension but it seems to only work with minikube??

What trouble are you running into?  Do you have a specific error message, or a [mcve]?
